# Caching PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, caching, dom

I am using the [PHP HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to pull data from an external website. To reduce load and speed up page rendering time I want to cache data I pull for a certain period. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote this file cache function which basically just replaces file_get_contents. You can specify the amount of time the cache should last for in `$offset` or completely override the cache with `$override`. If you don't want to use /tmp/, just change that directory to something you can read/write to.

```
function cache_get_contents($url, $offset = 600, $override = false) {
    $file = '/tmp/file_cache_' . md5($url);
    if (!$override && file_exists($file) && filemtime($file) > time() - $offset)
        return file_get_contents($file);

    $contents = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($contents === false)
        return false;

    file_put_contents($file, $contents);
    return $contents;
}
```

Comment: Right now I am using file_get_html which returns a DOM object. Right now yours returns a string

Comment: Use str_get_html() on the string.

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions for /tmp? Is file_get_contents() failing? You can try to debug the value of $contents after the 6th line of the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You could create local files with the HTML and then keep track of the file paths in the $SESSION.  If you have the disk space and can run a database, you could use a database to do the same thing.  A database connection and query on the URL you're looking for won't add much overhead at all.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to save the data to a database or local file. You could then use a timestamp column or file modification time to determine whether to continue using the cache or pull and save a fresh copy.

If you have access to some kind of memory caching (e.g. memcached) that would be ideal.

Comment: memcached is a good idea unless you have to store large amounts of data. It sounds like a file cache is more ideal in this situation.

Comment: @dtbame, fair enough. The OP didn't specify the amount of data. So I offered it as a secondary.