# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser caching multiple pages

Tags: php, dom, caching, simple-html-dom

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and using **$html->load_file**

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('https://www.google.com/finance?q=goog');
```

the link below demonstrates a method to force caching of the content.  I need to retrieve pages where the content changes depending on the last part of the url.  Is it possible to modify the code below to force caching, for example, if I retrieve the following pages:

google.com/finance?q=goog

google.com/finance?q=wwwfx

google.com/finance?q=vigrx

Can I cache each one of those pages until the end of the session because I will need the page content repeatedly.

[Caching PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039230/caching-php-simple-html-dom-parser?rq=1)

```
function cache_get_contents($url, $offset = 600, $override = false) {
    $file = '/tmp/file_cache_' . md5($url);
    if (!$override && file_exists($file) && filemtime($file) > time() - $offset)
        return file_get_contents($file);

    $contents = file_get_contents($url);
    if ($contents === false)
        return false;

    file_put_contents($file, $contents);
    return $contents;
}
```

Comment: This is a lazy mans cache. Look into memcached. Or write code that looks at how old the file is and have it update the contents after n hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carter is pointing you in the right direction, you might find the following info helpful.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/output-caching-for-beginners/

http://www.phpfastcache.com/

http://www.wpulti.org/best-php-cache-scripts-classes/

http://codecanyon.net/item/php-simple-cache/4169137?ref=globalcube&ref=globalcube&clickthrough_id=384995784&redirect_back=true